# Scores in parent tags

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process, tag-score, tag-hierarchy

I'm trying to achieve my first bronze tag badge, but I'm realizing that this is very difficult, especially because of the version tags.

I mean, for example, I have some score on the [python-2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.7) tag, some on the [python-3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x) tag and some on the [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) tag too.

[python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) tag should be parent of [python-2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.7) and [python-3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x) tags, shouldn't it? And [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) tag should have the score of the addition of their children plus its own score.

I have the same problem with the tags [odoo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/odoo), [openerp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openerp), [odoo-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/odoo-8), [openerp-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openerp-8) (this last one must not exist I think), [openerp-7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openerp-7), etc... I have a bit score in each one, but the addition of all (some are synonym tags in fact) would make me be nearest to the bronze badge.

How do you do in these cases? Do you edit the tags of the questions you answer to correct them and get more score on a specific tag? (Example: as I said above, [openerp-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openerp-8) should not exist, it must be only [odoo-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/odoo-8). I have some score in [openerp-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openerp-8). Should I edit those questions to turn [openerp-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openerp-8) into [odoo-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/odoo-8) and centralize my score on [odoo-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/odoo-8) tag?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whatever you do, don't edit questions or answers **ONLY** to get you [stinkin' badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19522/158100) or imaginary internet points. Edit and tag to make better questions, with only relevant tags.

There is no [tag hierarchy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45438/a-proposal-for-tag-hierarchy-on-so) in the tag system on the Stack Exchange sites. It was considered in the design phase, IIRC, but it was dismissed and we never looked back.

If a question is not version specific (so the issue can occur in any version) I seen no harm in replacing it for the generic tag. If the issue is only applicable to a specific version adding the generic tag is of course not correct.

With regard the the [openerp-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openerp-8) tags it looks like you either want to suggest a synonym or a re-tag/burnination. If that is the case please make that a seprate question because we can then vote on that instance and collect opinions about the correctness of your claim.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I will not edit questions for the purpose of getting more score in certain tag.

Comment: @forvas but will do if the tags doesn't make any sense, right?

Answer (score 1):

> Do you edit the tags of the questions you answer to correct them

Yes.

> and get more score on a specific tag?

No. If you see a question with a **irrelevant tag**, by all means, edit it. Tags are for experts to find questions they want to answer, since they have some kind of expertise on them. Getting the tag badges should only be considered a nice side effect of a cleaner categorization of the question.